# WiX occasionally throwing cab file error in embedded cab project

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

I have a WiX installer which, every now and then, will produce an install package which will throw the error

"The cabinet file 'cab1.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package"

I have EmbedCab="yes" in my markup

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I am using WiX Toolset v3.9.1208.0

Thank you

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?